# Как можно сделать часть текста, в ресурсе array жирным?

Tags: java, android

В ресурсах  в файле `arrays` есть текст.

```
<string-array name="opisanString">
    <item>текст <b>жирный шрифт</b></item>
    <item>текст</item>
</string-array>
```

Затем я получаю доступ к `TextView` и вставляю текст.

```
private TextView mTitleOpis;
    mTitleOpis = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.opisan);
    mTitleOpis.setText(mModel.getOpis());
```

Но шрифт не меняется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как пишут в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) (см. раздел "Styling with HTML markup") строковые ресурсы, которые получаются методами `getString()`, `getStringArray()` и т.д. теряют информацию о стиле строки. Вам можно только посоветовать экранировать html-теги, и затем самому форматировать.

Сделайте так: замените все `<` на `&lt;`

Т.е. так:

```
<string-array name="opisanString">
<item>текст &lt;b>жирный шрифт&lt;/b></item>
<item>текст</item>
</string-array>
```

Теперь на выходе вы получите строку `текст <b>жирный шрифт</b>`

Не знаю, что скрывается у вас за конструкцией:

```
mTitleOpis.setText(mModel.getOpis());
```

Но если вы таким образом просто получаете строки из `<string-array name="opisanString">`, то форматируйте так:

```
mTitleOpis.setText(Html.fromHtml(mModel.getOpis()));
```